# conjoint or something else

Tags: r, model-selection, conjoint-analysis, mlogit

I have shown customers two products with certain attributes and asked them to select one of the products. I have done this 12 times
with different combinations for each customer. I have a total number of 1000 customers.

Is there a modeling technique that I can apply to calculate which attributes most customers prefer? If possible, can someone also point me
to a working example in R or any other software?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is **discrete choice modelling**.
I would start with a multinomial logit (MNL) model which will model the choice probability as a function of product attributes.
This type of model can easily be implemented in R with many packages:
"**mlogit**" (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf).
You could also use the "**clogit**" function from the "**survival**" package (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/clogit.html).
For more sophisticated choice models there are many other packages: gmnl, bayesm, rsghb, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Another quick question as a follow up. In my 12 questions asked to the customers my attributes are changing each time. Is it fine to go ahead with discrete choice modeling